# REST API heart beat standard

Tags: rest, api, saas, heartbeat

For a SaaS product which provide its services via REST API, is it a standard requirement to have a heartbeat API?

I have a debate on this subject at work, in my point of view, the heartbeat API is redundant - in case of outages we have a status page which is exactly for those kind of issues, status page + proper communication,

And for the regular usage of our API -> the API should be consumed as is, and it should have a failover with a proper handling - depends on the consumer and the response code (writing to log, retry, etc...)

Also, I have never encountered an API product which provides a heartbeat endpoint, and while looking online I encountered Opsginie heartbeat proxy capability and other few heartbeats which I don't consider them as standard APIs,

Have you encountered such requirement for an API or encountered an API product which provides a heartbeat endpoint ? That will be really useful for me.

Comment: If you are using netcore, there is something already built-in for that (health checks)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a good question.  My suggestion is to focus on the consumers of your API and their expectations - ie how mission critical is the API?.  If your system was experiencing a severe issue, would your consumer:

1. probably be annoyed and look for notifications / status information (ie wait)?
2. panic and start raising priority one support calls?

If your consumers consider your API to be mission critical, they may well be looking for an *automated* way of detecting an issue even if they aren't currently using the API for it's main purpose.  A lot of mission-critical systems are hooked into monitoring systems of the client and so a heartbeat might be considered highly important for some users/clients/consumers.

If not typically mission critical, then your consumers will probably never use it so no need to implement.

I hope that helps.

Comment: First of all, I really liked your answer, 
Second, I encountered some SaaS products with status page where you can subscribe to events like outages and incidents (codeship, bitbucket, etc...) - I think that this might be a good solution for the "...automated way of detecting an issue...".

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  If the subscribe can be hooked into automatic notifications/monitoring on your side then everyone should be satisfied.  One thing to note is that the notifications of incidents/outages is slightly different from a heart-beat since the incident/outage notification is typically human initiated on the vendor-side (so might be deferred/subjective).

Comment: Hey! You might also recommend to developers that consume your API a way to monitor it in their app. Have a look at [Bearer.sh](https://www.bearer.sh). That's what we do.